# Dropbox Core API for Android: Not returning after Authentication

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, android-activity, dropbox

I am developing two android applications:

- the first is a normal application with a launcher and so on
- the other is a application only with a viewer activity (see the manifest):

  ```
  <activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon"
      android:label="@string/dropbox" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity
      android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
      android:launchMode="singleTask" >
      <intent-filter>
          <data android:scheme="db-XXXXX" />

          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ```

The plan is, that the first application does not need internet permissions and the second is some kind of add-on to the first.

The second application should sync a file with Dropbox (with the Core API, not with the Sync API).

From my first app, I start 'MyActivity' from the second app like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("my.package","my.package.MyActivity"));
    intent.putExtra("filePath", "/myFile.txt");
    startActivityForResult(intent, SYNC_REQUEST);
```

That works. The Activity comes up and there, if not authorized yet, the user must press a button. Then the following code will be executed

```
    AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
    mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);

    mApi.getSession().startAuthentication(MyActivity.this);
```

If the user does not have dropbox installed, the browser will pop up.

### Now my troubles begin:

As soon as the user presses 'Accept' or 'Decline', the browser does not disappear. It stays open and MyActivity does not get resumed (onResume is not called!).

I found out, that adding

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

before starting MyActivity from my first application will solve the problem, but then I can not listen/wait for the result of MyActivity.

I am frustrated. Can anyone help me or give me some advise?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find a way to solve this problem? My activity just closes after I select "Allow"

Answer (score 0):

When you are using startAuthentication method. It will automatically start the AuthActivity. you do not need to call startActivity() explicitly. Then in onResume method of your activity write this code :

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        if (if dropBoxAPI!= null && dropboxAPI.getSession().authenticationSuccessful())
        {
            try {

                dropboxAPI.getSession().finishAuthentication();
                oAuth2Token = dropboxAPI.getSession().getOAuth2AccessToken();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```